# Force an Android app to use mobile data without turning wifi off

Tags: android, networking

My app sometimes needs to connect via mobile data in order to work. I know there are apps that can make a certain app use only mobile data and I know how I can turn off and on the wifi with my app. But is there a way to tell my app to use mobile connection from now on and at another point remove this restriction?

Answer (score 0):

You can't explicitly force the communications channel on a per-app basis (you can request to use a preferred mode via `ConnectivityManager.setNetworkPreference(...)`, but that's not "forcing").

```
 // and to be sure:
   ConnectivityManager.setNetworkPreference(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
```

Comment: what do u need manager for? your first line doesn't do anything, does it?

Comment: Yes  I edited code but at that time you have to turn off wifi